# Numbers with the same base

Tags: python, list, exponent

I'm quite new to python and need help; i have built a program that finds the prime factors of a number, for example:
Input: `64` Output: `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]` (the factors are stored in a list)
but I want to join the numbers with the same base, and write them in the following form:
`64 = (2^6)`, or `360 = (2^3)*(3^2)*5`

I cannot figure out a way to do that, can someone please help me?

Comment: Please show your current program

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you are looking for is `Counter` from the `collections` module.

The usage is very straightforward:

```
from collections import Counter

dividers_counter = Counter(dividers)
```

It will contain the dividers as keys and the number of occurrence as values: `Counter({2: 3, 3: 2})`